# Add whitespace to string in Coldfusion

Tags: string, coldfusion, append, concatenation, whitespace

I need to add whitespace onto the end of a string.

ColdFusion seems to be automatically removing any whitespace I try to add, I'll sometimes get 1 empty space character but that's it.

I have an input field, a string, that can be up to 7 characters long. If the input is less than 7 characters, I'm to pad the end with spaces.

Does anyone know of a quick, easy, intuitive way to accomplish this using coldfusion. As little code as possible is preferred.

Some of the solutions I tried were:

```
 #LEFT(FORM.strInput & '       ', 7)#

 #LEFT(FORM.strInput & '        0', 7)#

 #REPLACE(LEFT(FORM.strInput & 0000000, 7), '0', ' ', 'all')#

<CFLOOP FROM="1" TO="7 - LEN(FORM.strInput)">
  <CFSET FORM.strInput = FORM.strInput & ' '>
</CFLOOP>

<CFLOOP FROM="1" TO="7 - LEN(FORM.strInput)">
  <CFSET FORM.strInput = FORM.strInput & '&nbsp;'>
</CFLOOP>
```

Comment: Your first commented out piece of code gets the job done.  What are you looking at that makes you think it doesn't?

Comment: For use where? If you mean display space characters within html, it automatically collapses extra space characters i.e. `chr(32)`. You must use a non-breaking space, `&nbsp;`, instead. https://trycf.com/gist/6e3557b943a2cf90b724fb7a86572e77/acf2018?theme=monokai

Comment: When I output the variable to the screen, only 1 space is displayed. Ex. if the input is 'BB1' it'll show 'BB1 ' instead of 'BB1' + space x7 but the LEN() function states there are 7 characters so I'm not sure.

Comment: @Agreax Based on what you're saying, as long as the LEN() function is returning the right number of characters, I should be good? I'm using this input to fill a parameter of a custom cf tag. I need to pass this variable, with the spaces, to the custom cf tag. Will the spaces be passed along with the string?

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: @JimmyGoodson - Yes. Never rely on what you "see" when dealing with white space.  It'll bite you. Use more reliable tools, like checking the string length and looping through the characters and checking for the correct ascii value. https://trycf.com/gist/d1b63168a3aafa5be7f2222f7ea5d712/acf2018?theme=monokai

Comment: Jimmy,  if the `len()` function tells you the length is 7, then it's 7.  As @Agreax said, never rely on what you see with whitespace.  A couple of ways to verify your output is to use **Inpect Element** in your developer tools.  Another option is to display the output using the preformatted text tag `<pre>...<pre>` as this tag does not ignore whitespace.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use repeatString()

```
<cfset form.strInput = form.strInput & repeatString( ' ', max( 7-len(form.strInput), 0 ) ) />
```

But, keep in mind, if you try to display multiple consecutive spaces on a web page, the browser will only 'display' the first one.

Comment: One issue with your code solution.  if `len(form.strInput)` is greater than 7, then this will throw an error since the second argument would become a negative number.

Comment: Fixed that issue

Comment: If you're not using an old version of ACF, may I suggest using `&=` for concatenation, which both ACF and Lucee now support: `form.strInput &= repeatString()`

Answer (score 2):

I like Scott's answer, but I would refine it a bit.

```
<script>
form.strInput &= repeatString(' ', max(7 - len(form.strInput), 0));
</script>
```

Comment: There is no functional difference between this code and the code I posted.

Comment: Just less typing by using `&=`